# Creating a multidimensional array from row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I take an array such as this:

```
Array ( [key1] => item1 [key2] => item2 [key3] => item3 [key4] => item4 [key5] => item5 [key6] => item6 )
```

php:

```
$array = array('key1' => 'item1','key2' =>  'item2', 'key3' => 'item3','key4' =>  'item4', 'key5' => 'item5','key6' =>  'item6');
```

and create a multidimensional array with every 3 values as an array, such as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => item1 [1] => item2 [2] => item3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => item4 [1] => item5 [2] => item6 ) )
```

php:

```
$array = array(array('item1','item2','item3'),
              array('item4','item5','item6'));
```

So that I can output the different items like: `$newArray[0][1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_chunk()](http://docs.php.net/array_chunk) - Split an array into chunks

```
$array = array('key1' => 'item1','key2' =>  'item2', 'key3' => 'item3','key4' =>  'item4', 'key5' => 'item5','key6' =>  'item6');
$a2 = array_chunk($array, 3);
echo $a2[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array();
$vals = array_values($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 3) {
 $new[] = array_slice($vals, $i, 3);
}
```