# Modify multidimensional array inside a function in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function that modifies an array like this:

```
function addDataToArray($array,array("data","userdata","username"),"john") { // do something here }
```

result will be $array["data"]["userdata"]["username"]="john"

I'm aware that it would be much easier to achieve this in normal ways but I need to learn if this can be done. 
Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? I'm not writing your function for you.

Comment: I guess that the thing that you need is the reference notion : http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php. If not, please answer Zarathuztra's question, and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should works for you. I was a little bit inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108379/php-create-multidimensional-array-from-flat-one):

```
function addDataToArray(&$array,$input_array,$string) { 

    $count = count($input_array)-1;
    $tmp = array($input_array[$count]=>$string);

    for ($i=$count-1;$i>=0;$i--) {
        $arr = array();
        $arr[$input_array[$i]] = $tmp;
        $tmp = $arr;
    }

    $array = array_merge($array, $arr);
}

$array = array(); //or your inicialized $array
addDataToArray($array,array("data","userdata","username"),"john");

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea behind it.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion

```
$array = array("foo" => "bar"); 

function addDataToArray(&$a, $path, $val) 
{ 
    if (count($path) == 1) { 
        $path = $path[0]; 
    } 
    if (!is_array($path)) { 
        $a[$path] = $val; 
        return $a; 
    } 
    $b = array(); 
    $a[array_shift($path)] = addDataToArray($b, $path, $val); 
    return $a; 
} 
addDataToArray($array, array("data","userdata","username"),"john"); 
var_dump($array);
```

Result

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["userdata"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["username"]=>
      string(4) "john"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code doesn't work - it is not generating multidimensional array.