# Convert array of values to nested associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

[php create multidimensional array from flat one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108379/php-create-multidimensional-array-from-flat-one)

Tried this but counting backwards won't work as I need to move from start to finish in the order in which the array is originally.

I have a simple array:

```
0 => Item #1
1 => Item #2 
2 => Item #3
```

I need to create an associative array from the above like so:

```
Item #1 
  => Item #2 
    => Item #3
```

Where each value becomes the key for the parent item. This must be done in a while loop not recursion. It MUST move forward, the loop performs a look-ahead for validation purposes, so the original order is imperative

Thanks

EDIT - this is giving me the intended result I just can't get my around how to do this in the main loop |

```
array:3 [
  0 => "workorder"
  1 => "company"
  2 => "name"
]

$array['workorder'] = [];
$temp = &$array['workorder'];
$temp['company'] = [];

$temp2 = &$temp['company'];
$temp2['name'] = [];

dump($array);
exit;
```

EDIT 2 | Main loop

```
$type = current($types);
while (array_key_exists($type, $this->types)) {
    $nextType = next($types);

    // ... do stuff 

    $type = $nextType;
}

return $array;
```

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far.

Comment: It is literally one or two lines causing me issues - I have experimented with something like `$temp2 = $array[$type]; $array &= $temp2;` but that gives me undefined index notices, and simply doesn't work. I might have to change the implementation to move backwards, wrapping each child in it's parent element - however that requires re-working a bunch of code that breaks out of the loop so please excuse my hesitation to do so :)

Comment: For what it is worth I have a look-ahead involved so I actually know the current element and the next (if any)

Comment: What does the main loop look like?

Comment: I added what I am trying to work into the loop - as a series of hardcoded instructions it works as expected but obviously I need this to be dynamic :p I also threw in the main loop - its just a simple while() but as it steps through each element, it performs a look-ahead to validate each step.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// This array contain the keys for associative array
    $arrayKeys = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

    // This array contain the values for associative array
    $arrayItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    // this array will be the associative array
    $newArray = [];      
    $count = count($arrayKeys) -1;
    while( $count >= 0 ){
        $newArray[ $arrayKeys[$count] ] = $arrayItems[$count];
        echo '<Br>';
        $count--;
    }
```